# Image getting cropped according to view port by using layout.getDrawingCache()

Tags: android, image-processing

I have a absolute layout  which contain 2 buttons and a dynamically added image . Image width and height are larger than screen size and is scrollable in both directions . I need to place a dynamic text on this image . The text view is added at runtime and is drag-gable  to anywhere in image .
After placing text view at required position i need to store image with the dynamically placed text. For this I am using below code

```
absView.setDrawingCacheEnabled (true);              
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(absView.getDrawingCache());
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
absView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

But the bitmap contains only the visible view not the hidden view of the whole image which is larger than screen-size.
How can I get whole layout view to be captured in bitmap with dynamically placed textview ?

Answer (score 0):

you wont be able to as `absView.getDrawingCache()` get you the drawing cache of the view, 
for portions that are not visible, no cache wud be stored, i think

if you are looking to merge bitmaps this might help you

[combining two png files in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738834/combining-two-png-files-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this will work but worth a try

```
 Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth,viewHeight,Bitmapconfig);
 Canvas viewCanvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
 absView.draw(viewCanvas);
```

After this viewBitmap might have the full view drawn into it.

The drawingcache will not have the full view as only the visible portion of the view is drawn and that is what is cached.