# android magnifying glass effect

Tags: android, effects

I wonder if it is possible for a Widget to create an area that works as a magnifying glass over whatever background the user has set.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An other solution could be to read the image path, add a "transparent glass image" or effect. Save as new image and set it as new wallpaper.

Comment: i mean an overlay image like: http://www.musingsfrommars.org/images/iweb/CCI2.0_screenshots/crystal_overlay.png

so you have to write a image editor :)

how to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738834/combining-two-png-files-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not possible. It implies that you can read the pixels of other activities, and if that was possible, there would be a way to take a screenshot of the phone programatically.