# how to combine photo and image in one?

Tags: android, image, camera

I need to get a picture and superimpose one image on top and be able to record a single image of an idea how in Android?

so please help me

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738834/combining-two-png-files-in-android

Answer (score 0):

use this in xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:background="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_launcer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
        android:background="@drawable/image2" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: See the link I put in a comment in your question to find the code for what you are looking for..