# BitmapFactory.decodeFile cannot be resolved in to a type

Tags: android, cordova, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to combine 2 images so i searched and saw a code snipplet here [combining two png files in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738834/combining-two-png-files-in-android)

```
Bitmap bottomImage = new BitmapFactory.decodeFile("myFirstPNG.png");
Bitmap topImage = new BitmapFactor.decodeFile("myOtherPNG.png");


Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bottomImage);
// Then draw the second on top of that
comboImage.drawBitmap(topImage, 0f, 0f, null);

// bottomImage is now a composite of the two. 

// To write the file out to the SDCard:
OutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/" + "myNewFileName.png");
    image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os)
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried to use it but for some reason **Bitmap bottomImage = new BitmapFactory.decodeFile("myFirstPNG.png");** is giving a error that BitmapFactory cannot be resovlved into a type but i already have both

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
```

I am using phonegap and i put this in the main activity to test

Comment: remove "new" in the Bitmap bottomImage = new BitmapFactory.decodeFile("myFirstPNG.png");
Bitmap topImage = new BitmapFactor.decodeFile("myOtherPNG.png");

Answer (score 4):

[`decodeFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) is a static method that needs to be called in the class scope as follows:

```
Bitmap bottomImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("myFirstPNG.png");
Bitmap topImage = BitmapFactor.decodeFile("myOtherPNG.png");
```

(notice that the `new` keyword has been dropped)

Comment: oh so the new should bit be there?

Comment: fixed the problem but when i run i get a null pointer error in this line **Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bottomImage);** and im sure i put the image in the same directory to test still get error