# Combine two image in app and taking result as single image

Tags: android, image, photo

I have an android app which can send screen shots to share on Facebook. What I want is adding some stuffs like my app logo/icon on image and save that as a single image and share that on Facebook. (something like what heel climb racing does).

How can I combine Images? A sample code or tutorial would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class to work with images.

Check this SO question for more details: [combining two png files in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738834/combining-two-png-files-in-android)

Comment: Thank you. I have two little questions; 1- in draw bitmap, what are `float top` and `float left`? 2- How can I set text over an image and save as a single image?

Comment: 1. I guess that `top` and `left` represent the position where you want the bitmap to be drawn (relative to the canvas)

Comment: 2. There is a Canvas#drawText method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)