# Render 2 Images together in Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have looked multiple places on how should I approach making an application that will render 2 images together (user selects an image from their gallery and then they can add a couple PNG images on top of it and save the image back to their gallery). If you can point me in the direction that I would need to look, that would be great thanks!

Comment: Read this link, this has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738834/combining-two-png-files-in-android/2739011#2739011

Comment: wow, sorry about that, thanks though!