# How do I distort an image on Android?

Tags: java, android

I new to programming and even newer to Android. I have managed to take a picture and then draw on it. I was wondering how i could now distort the image, lets say i take a picture of someones head, if i draw a circle around the head it would distort it.
This would just result in a funny image that is its purpose nothing serious just fun.

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, next time you post a question make sure the title sums up your problem. using "How is this done" kind of titles are very bad for other users to understand what you want at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a look at how to achieve Image Processing on Android, then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043019/image-processing-on-android). 
 Other than that, it is just an Image Processing question and nothing specific to Android/Java. You can do it in the same way as in any other platform.